# Openshift Origin Latest Project creation issue

Tags: openshift-origin

I am unable to create project in open shift. I created a project previously and deleted it. Looks like a project exists but unable to access or delete it. Seems like i am stuck. Also logging into the console https://console.preview.openshift.com/console/ doesn't show any existing projects.

I ran the following oc commands from the terminal.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

XX:~ XX$ **oc new-project test**
Error from server: projectrequests "test" is forbidden: user XX cannot create more than 1 project(s).

XX:~ XX$ **oc delete project test**
Error from server: User "XX" cannot delete projects in project "test"

XX:~ XX$ **oc status**
Error from server: User "XX" cannot get projects in project "default"

### XX:~ XX$ **oc get projects**

Answer (score 0):

You need to give privileges/policies to your user which will allow the actions you want to perform.
If you are just in a proof-of-concept environment I would recommend the make your user cluster-admin in the whole cluster. This will give all the possible privileges to your user. Of course this in't recommended for every user in a 'real' environment.

First you need to authenticate with the 'default admin' which is created after the installation. This default admin-user isn't working with the normal user/password authentication. It's using a client certificate.

```
oc login -u system:admin --config=/etc/origin/master/admin.kubeconfig
```

Now you will see a list of the available projects (default, openshift management, etc). Now you're able to give cluster-roles to other users.
Make your user cluster-admin over the whole cluster

```
oadm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin (youruser)
```

Now you have the cluster-admin privileges inside the whole cluster. You are also able to give privileges for some user in a specific project and not in the whole cluster. Than you have to use:

```
oadm policy add-role-to-user <role> <username> (in the current project)
```

This will give the role to a user, but only inside the project from where you've performed this command.
For more information about the avaiable cluster roles and policies I will point to the [official documentation](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/manage_authorization_policy.html).

Comment: Thanks. I could not try this command. I got an error --- The connection to the server localhost:8443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Comment: you have to specify the master-url to login: `oc login -u system:admin --config=/etc/origin/master/admin.kubeconfig https://your-master-url:8443` (the url which to which you are surfing to see the webconsole)

Answer (score 0):

I raised a defect with Openshift Team as pointed out in the Support Link. 
https://docs.openshift.com/online/getting_started/devpreview_faq.html#devpreview-faq-support

Here is the response i received from Support Team.

It seems that you have issued a bug and followed up for this already:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1368862
After the cause is investigated, our operations team will sure clean up the project manually for you to allow you continue working with the developer preview

Latest update:

The project has now been cleaned up and you should be able to create a new project.

I am able to create Project in Openshift now.